# Check if a number is just after or just before a number

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have four numbers, say `2`,`3`,`4`,`6`, and I want to check, do they come before or after a number. For example, if I select `2`, then I want the code to say `3` is just after the number; and when I select `3`, the code should output `2` comes just before `3` and `4` comes just after `3`; and when I select `4` the code Should output 3 comes just before `4`. How do I achieve this in Python?
this is what I have tried so far...

```
a = [2,3,4,6]
def check(noToCheck, List):
    if noToCheck in List:
        for elem in List:
            if noToCheck == elem+1:
                print elem+" comes just before "+noToCheck
            elif noToCheck == elem-1:
                print elem+" comes just after "+noToCheck
            else:
                pass
```

this works well but what is the cleaner way to do it

Comment: just a couple of `if else` statements

Comment: can you share that here, so that we can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes in a value, called num (e.g. 5) and then checks to see if it's adjacent numbers (e.g. 4 and 6) are in the array, and if they are, then it will print them.

```
def getContext(arr,num):
    if (num+1 in arr):
        print str(num+1) + " is after and in the array"        
    if (num-1 in arr):
        print str(num-1) + " is before and in the array"

arr = [2,3,4,6]

getContext(arr,2)
```

Comment: *best* is a heavy word.

Comment: I changed it to *a*.

Comment: this is not What I want  it tells according to the index of the array, I want it to say according to the integers inside the list

Comment: That is exactly what it is doing.  Try to input "6" into the formula.

Comment: I reposted the code.  Instead, this time it uses print statements to make it easier to read.

Comment: That is not what I want when input 6 in the formula it should not return anything because 4 does not comes just before 6, 5 should be the answer but 5 is not in the list so there should be no answer returned